# numpy, Select elements in rows by 1d indexes array

Tags: python, numpy

Let we have square array, n*n. For example, n=3 and array is this:

```
arr = array([[0, 1, 2],
   [3, 4, 5],
   [6, 7, 8]])
```

And let we have array of indices in the each ROW. For example:

```
myidx=array([1, 2, 1], dtype=int64)
```

I want to get:

> [1, 5, 7]

Because in line [0,1,2] take element with index 1, in line [3,4,5] get element with index 2, in line [6,7,8] get element with index 1.

I'm confused, and can't take elements this way using standard numpy indexing.
Thank you for answer.

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is a better way, but for a start: ``numpy.array([arr[i, j] for (i, j) in enumerate(myidx)])``

Comment: That's not interesting. I wanna use clear numpy indexing :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no real pretty way but this does what you are looking for :)

```
In [1]: from numpy import *

In [2]: arr = array([[0, 1, 2],
   [3, 4, 5],
   [6, 7, 8]])

In [3]: myidx = array([1, 2, 1], dtype=int64)

In [4]: arr[arange(len(myidx)), myidx]
Out[4]: array([1, 5, 7])
```

Comment: Cool! This really pretty, don't doubt!

Comment: @QtRoS: numpy slicing supports multiple dimensions so the `arange()` generates the `x` indices and the `myidx` contains the `y` indices. So it's slicing like this: `arr[x_idx, y_idx]`

Answer (score 1):

Simpler way to reach the goal is using [choose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html) numpy function:

```
numpy.choose(myidx, arr.transpose())
```